# Dask to Flatten Dictionary Column

Tags: python, pandas, dask, flatten

I am new to Dask and am looking to find a way to flatten a dictionary column in a PANDAS dataframe. Here is a screenshot of the first row of a 16 million-row dataframe:

[image: screenshot of first two rows of data]

And here is a sample of the text from three rows:

```
{{u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT': u'0', u'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME': u'DEBRA MEALY', u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER': u'0', u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED': u'0', u'F9_07_PZ_TITLE': u'CHAIR PERSON', u'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK': u'1.00', u'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL': u'X'}, {u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT': u'0', u'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME': u'HELEN GORDON', u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER': u'0', u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED': u'0', u'F9_07_PZ_TITLE': u'VICE CHAIR', u'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK': u'1.00', u'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL': u'X'}, {'F9_07_PC_HIGH_COMP_EMPLOYEE': 'X', 'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME': 'ROB S KHANUJA', 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER': '14902', 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED': '0', 'F9_07_PZ_TITLE': 'EXEC. DIR. OPERATIONS', 'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK': '40.00', 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT': '133173'}}
```

I would normally flatten the *Form990PartVIISectionAGrp* column with the following code:

```py
    df = pd.concat([df.drop(['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'], axis=1), df['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'].swifter.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

I'm looking to do this in Dask but am getting the following error: "ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata."

I am using Python 2.7. I import the relevant packages

```py
    from dask import dataframe as dd
    from dask.multiprocessing import get
    from multiprocessing import cpu_count
    nCores = cpu_count()
```

To test the code, I created a random sample of the data:

```py
    dfs = df.sample(1000)
```

And then generate the Dask dataframe:

```py
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(dfs, npartitions=nCores)
```

The column is currently in string format so I convert it to a dictionary. Normally, I would just write one line of code:

```py
dfs['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'] = dfs['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'].apply(literal_eval)
```

But I've instead tried to do it here in a more 'Dask-like' form so I write the following function and then apply it:

```py
    def make_dict(dfs):
        dfs['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'] = dfs['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'].apply(literal_eval)   
        return dfs
```

```py
    ddf_out = ddf.map_partitions(make_dict, meta=dfs[:0]).compute()
```

This works -- it returns a PANDAS dataframe where the Form990PartVIISectionAGrp column is in dictionary format (it's not any faster than the non-Dask apply, however).

[image: ddf_out]

I then re-create the Dask DF:

```py
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(ddf_out, npartitions=nCores)
```

And write a function to flatten the column:

```py
    def flatten(ddf_out):
        ddf_out = pd.concat([ddf_out.drop(['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'], axis=1), ddf_out['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
        #ddf_out = ddf_out['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'].apply(pd.Series)
    return ddf_out
```

If I then run this code:

```py
    result = ddf.map_partitions(flatten)
```

I get the following output, where the column has not been flattened:

[image: result]

I was also getting errors about missing meta data, and given that the above did not help parse the dictionary column, so I created a list of the columns produced by the plain Python flattening of the columns and used that to create a dictionary of the columns and data types:

```py
metadir = {u'BusinessName': 'O', u'F9_07_PC_FORMER': 'O', u'F9_07_PC_HIGH_COMP_EMPLOYEE': 'O',
       u'F9_07_PC_KEY_EMPLOYEE': 'O', u'F9_07_PC_OFFICER': 'O',
       u'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL': 'O', u'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INSTITUTIONAL': 'O',
       u'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK': 'O', u'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK_RELATED': 'O',
       u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT': 'O', u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER': 'O',
       u'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED': 'O', u'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME': 'O',
       u'F9_07_PZ_TITLE': 'O', u'NameBusiness': 'O', u'URL': 'O'}
```

I then apply the flatten function with this meta data:

```py
    result = ddf.map_partitions(flatten, meta=metadir)
```

I get the following output as result:

[image: result]

Running result.columns yields this:

[image: result.columns]

Where this fails is in running compute(), where I get the following error message: "ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata." I get the same error whether I write:

```py
result.compute()
```

or

```py
result.compute(meta=metadir)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The columns in *result* seem to match those in *metadir*. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: 
Here is my stab at updating the flatten function.

```py
    meta = pd.DataFrame(columns=['URL', 'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL',
     'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME',
     'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER',
     'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED',
     'F9_07_PZ_TITLE',
     'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK',
     'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT',
     'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK_RELATED',
     'F9_07_PC_OFFICER',
     'F9_07_PC_HIGH_COMP_EMPLOYEE',
     'BusinessName',
     'F9_07_PC_KEY_EMPLOYEE',
     'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INSTITUTIONAL',
     'NameBusiness',
     'F9_07_PC_FORMER'], dtype="O")

    def flatten(ddf_out):
        ddf_out = pd.concat([df.drop(['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'], axis=1), df['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
        for m in meta:
            if m not in ddf_out:
                df[m] = '' 
        return ddf_out
```

Then I run:

```py
result = ddf.map_partitions(flatten, meta=meta).compute()
```

Comment: Above is some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of notes to get started:

> .apply(literal_eval)

Wouldn't this be better as `map`?

> I then re-create the Dask DF:
>
> ddf = dd.from_pandas(ddf_out, npartitions=nCores)

`ddf_out` was already a dask dataframe, I don't know why you had to do this.

> The columns in result seem to match those in metadir.

The value of `result.columns` is taken from the meta you provided, no computing happens until you ask for it (dask is lazy in most operations). Does the ValueError exception not provide further information?

Here is a full example

```
x = ({'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT': '0',
  'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME': 'DEBRA MEALY',
  'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER': '0',
  'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED': '0',
  'F9_07_PZ_TITLE': 'CHAIR PERSON',
  'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK': '1.00',
  'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL': 'X'},
 {'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT': '0',
  'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME': 'HELEN GORDON',
  'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER': '0',
  'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED': '0',
  'F9_07_PZ_TITLE': 'VICE CHAIR',
  'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK': '1.00',
  'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL': 'X'})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': x})
d = dd.from_pandas(df, 1)
meta = pd.DataFrame(columns=['F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT', 
       'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME',
       'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER', 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED', 'F9_07_PZ_TITLE',
       'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK', 'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL'], dtype="O")
d.map_partitions(lambda df: df.a.apply(pd.Series), meta=meta).compute()
```

How did I know what `meta` to use? I applied the function to the pandas dataframe - you might use a small piece of the dataframe to do this.

Some additional notes:

- it is an anti-pattern to load the data with pandas, pass to dask workers and then gather the whole result back to a pandas (in memory) dataframe, you are very unlikely to see a speedup this way and may incur a lot of overhead. You are better off loading with something like `dd.read_csv`, and aggregating or writing with dask functions too. Only `compute()` on something that will be small or not return anything (because it involves writing the output). The official examples do not use from_pandas.
- string and dict processing are python methods, and so hold the interpreter lock (GIL) of any python function: threads will not actually run in parallel. To get parallelism, you need to run in processes, which is most easily achieved using https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html
- the distributed scheduler also gives you access to the dashboard, which has a lot of useful information to diagnose how your system is running. You can also configure  a lot about its behaviour, in case you have firewall rules you need to obey.

Comment: Thank you for the notes. First off, this is the first time I've used Dask. To answer your question about apply(literal_eval) vs. map(literal_eval), I don't really know. I just went in an tried map and it worked but was slightly slower than apply. As for ddf_out, that was just for testing -- but from the output I showed above it was a PANDAS DF rather than a Dask DF -- isn't that what compute does? You're right, though, I did not need to do that -- I was just checking that the compute would work for the literal_eval, which it did.

Comment: ... I pasted in some sample data. I also re-ran the above code by not running compute at the literal_eval stage and not re-creating the Dask dataframe -- same error message. I can't see anything important in the ValueError message. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. It doesn't work in Python 2.7 but I did get it to work in 3.6 with your sample code. I did take your approach and determine the meta from applying it to the PANDAS dataframe -- that's how I created the metadir above. My apologies, but I made a mistake in the two samples I provided -- both have the same keys, which is not always the case. The issue may lie in the fact that in the total dataset, there are the keys I listed in metadir -- but that not every record will have every key. I tried your approach and updated meta as shown in the following comment but same ValueError:

Comment: meta = pd.DataFrame(columns=['F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL',
 'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME',
 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER',
 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED',
 'F9_07_PZ_TITLE',
 'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK',
 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT',
 'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK_RELATED',
 'F9_07_PC_OFFICER',
 'F9_07_PC_HIGH_COMP_EMPLOYEE',
 'BusinessName',
 'F9_07_PC_KEY_EMPLOYEE',
 'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INSTITUTIONAL',
 'NameBusiness',
 'F9_07_PC_FORMER'], dtype="O")

Comment: I updated answer above to include three sample rows with different keys.

Comment: You need to make each partition have the same keys, so please change your `flatten` function appropriately. Meta should, then, include all these keys.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm not sure exactly what you mean, though. How exactly would I change it?

Comment: Change your function (the `lambda`, above) to ensure that you always return a dataframe with all of the columns.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have updated my question to show my take on updating the lambda function -- does that look like a good way to you? This worked on a random sample of 1,000 rows but it's been running for a couple of hours on the whole dataset -- we'll see if it works, but so far even if it does work I'm not seeing any performance improvement given the length of time it's been running.

Comment: Performance is a very different question. Your process is GIL-holding, and you are going from pandas back to pandas. You should load the data partitions in the workers, and *use* them in the workers too, ideally processes. This is discussed in great detail elsewhere. Recommend you use the distributed scheduler, even in-process, so you can see which thread is doing what.

Comment: The code ultimately did not work on a dataset with 16 million rows. I do appreciate your help on this, but given how new Dask is to me I find your last comment quite vague. Can you provide any more specific details? Or at least a link?

Comment: You mean the dashboard? http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/web.html The distributed scheduler? http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks. No, this comment: "You should load the data partitions in the workers, and use them in the workers too, ideally processes." On a side note, this whole experience is really frustrating. The dashboard fails and/or breaks things on my Macbook and Windows server and does not work, while five days later I am still trying to get the above answer to actually work. I have read many Dask tutorials and Stack answers and have wasted a lot of time trying to get this to run.

Comment: OK, sorry you feel like that - but of course it doesn't fit into this comments thread. I tried to answer your problem as posed. Editing with some notes.

Comment: Thanks again for the help with this. Your comment above about not loading in the data from PANDAS was helpful and led me to the solution below. I appreciate all the hints.

Answer (score 0):

Given a small- or medium-sized dataset, the plain PANDAS solution would work:

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'], axis=1), df['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

However, with 16 million rows the PANDAS solution won't run on either a Macbook with 16GB of RAM or a Windows machine with 96GB. For that reason I looked to Dask. As seen in the above answer and comments, however, the Dask solution does not work because each observation in my dataset does not necessarily have all of the dictionary keys. Collectively, the 16 million observations of  *Form990PartVIISectionAGrp* have the 15 keys in the following list:

```
  newkeys = ['F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL',
 'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME',
 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER',
 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED',
 'F9_07_PZ_TITLE',
 'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK',
 'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT',
 'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK_RELATED',
 'F9_07_PC_OFFICER',
 'F9_07_PC_HIGH_COMP_EMPLOYEE',
 'BusinessName',
 'F9_07_PC_KEY_EMPLOYEE',
 'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INSTITUTIONAL',
 'NameBusiness',
 'F9_07_PC_FORMER']
```

So, my solution involved taking some of the hints provided by @mdurant above and first adding any missing keys to each row:

```
for index, row in df[:].iterrows():
    for k in newkeys:
        row['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp'].setdefault(k, np.nan)
```

That took 100 minutes on my Macbook. Based on mdurant's comment, I then saved the dataframe in JSON format:

```
df.to_json('df.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

And read the file into Dask as text:

```
import json
import dask.bag as db
b = db.read_text('df.json').map(json.loads)
```

Then create a function to flatten the column:

```
def flatten(record):
    return {
    'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER'],
    'F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PZ_COMP_RELATED'],
    'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INDIVIDUAL'],
    'F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PZ_DIRTRSTKEY_NAME'],
    'F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PZ_COMP_DIRECT'],
    'F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PZ_COMP_OTHER'],  
    'BusinessName': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['BusinessName'],  
    'F9_07_PC_FORMER': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PC_FORMER'],
    'F9_07_PC_HIGH_COMP_EMPLOYEE': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PC_HIGH_COMP_EMPLOYEE'],
    'F9_07_PC_KEY_EMPLOYEE': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PC_KEY_EMPLOYEE'],
    'F9_07_PC_OFFICER': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PC_OFFICER'],
    'F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INSTITUTIONAL': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PC_TRUSTEE_INSTITUTIONAL'],
    'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK'],
    'F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK_RELATED': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PZ_AVE_HOURS_WEEK_RELATED'],
    'F9_07_PZ_TITLE': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['F9_07_PZ_TITLE'],
    'NameBusiness': record['Form990PartVIISectionAGrp']['NameBusiness'],
    'URL': record['URL'],
}
```

I can then apply the function:

```
df = b.map(flatten).to_dataframe()
```

And export the data to CSV:

```
df.to_csv('compensation*.csv')
```

This works like a charm! In short, based on mdurant's helpful comments above, the keys are 1) to add missing keys to all observations and 2) to not read your data into Dask from PANDAS (use text or CSV instead). Taking care of those two issues led to a good solution to this problem.